# omap3 gpmc config in linux

Tags: linux-device-driver, omap

Is it possible to change configuration of a OMAP3 gpmc after boot-up on linux?  I am writing a driver for a device that use the OMAP3 gpmc bus.  We would prefer to be able to load the driver only when needed.  Would linux allow it, since the GPMC control also program memory?

Answer (score 2):

(If you haven't done it already, I suggest you join TI e2e community: there are many ongoing discussions about TI OMAP architecture and TI engineers overview the forums to provide answers).

You could specify a device driver as built-in or module when you configure the kernel. You can load that module later on with the insmod command. That option depends on your target architecture, of course.